# joomla 3 custom component checkout record

Tags: joomla, record, checkout, backend, custom-component

Iam in the edit view of one of my component views.
When I go back to the list view, with the cancel button of joomlas toolbar, the list view appears, but the record is locked. It seems that the record is not checked out correct.

In this case, there is no special function in the appropriate controler for canceling. Only for saving and some other tasks.

Iam not able to unlocking the records due to my view in the backend.

In the view there is a typical javascript for using the submit button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    js = jQuery.noConflict();
    js(document).ready(function() {

    });

        Joomla.submitbutton = function(task)
        {
            if (task == 'master.cancel') {
                Joomla.submitform(task, document.getElementById('master-form'));
            }
            else {
                if (task != 'master.cancel' && document.formvalidator.isValid(document.id('master-form'))) {

                    Joomla.submitform(task, document.getElementById('master-form'));
                }
                else {
                    alert('<?php echo $this->escape(JText::_('JGLOBAL_VALIDATION_FORM_FAILED')); ?>');
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Where should I go into, to activate the checkout function when leaving back to the listview from the edit view?

Same problem in case of saving records.

thx Perino

Comment: This is a standard thing in the core mvc classes, you should make your code match what is in the core components.  What is your table class extending?

Comment: Of course, I go along Joomlas MVC structure. The core components differs, dependig on their needs and I dont really find any big differences in their core meaning. My table class extending is JTable.

Comment: I found the problem. The view is build up of different models and I deactivated 

$this->item  = $this->get('Item');

in view.html.php. Activating, will result in correct checkin/out of the record.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The view is build up of different models and I deactivated

$this->item     = $this->get('Item');

in view.html.php. Activating, will result in correct checkin/out of the record.